# Constructor dependency code snippet in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net

I find myself adding dependencies a lot to constructors like so:

```
public class SomeClass() {
    private ISomeService _service;
    private IAnotherService _anotherService;
    public SomeClass(ISomeService service, IAnotherService anotherService) {
        _service = service;
        _anotherService = anotherService;
    }
}
```

They're quite tedious to write, I've been looking for code snippets in visual studio to automatically add one to the constructor but haven't found one.

What I want is:

- When adding a dependency to a constructor some snippet automatically creates a local variable and assigns to it.

OR

- Add a private variable and then some snippet automatically adds it to the constructor and assigns it to the local variable.

Comment: Specify the version of C# being targeting as well as visual studio version; that could provide a differing answers.

Comment: @OmegaMan vs 2015, .net 4.5

Comment: No idea, what you're asking. You want to generate a constructor by selecting private fields?

Comment: @Jannik yes, see my updated answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't have Resharper, you can add the parameter on the constructor, write the assignament to an unexisting property and hit CTRL+. . This will prompt you with the options to automatically create a property or field for you.

For example, you have this class:

```
public class MyClass 
{ 
    public MyClass()
    { 
    }
}
```

You then add the parameter to the constructor, and the assignament:

```
public class MyClass 
{ 
    public MyClass(IDependency myDependency)
    { 
         this.myDependency = myDependency;
    }
}
```

And hit CTRL+. while  on the asignament line, and select create field, and you'll get this:

```
public class MyClass 
{         
    IDependency myDependency;

    public MyClass(IDependency myDependency)
    { 
         this.myDependency = myDependency;
    }
}
```

Comment: VS 2017 - FIXED. See Simon Budin's question below: all this is automated now in much less work than this answer.

Answer (score 13):

If you have [R#](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) you can enter the field declarations and then highlight them and hit `Alt-Enter` which will give you the option to generate the constructor and field assignments.

[image]

Comment: Been using this for a few days now and it's really really nice.

Comment: Every once in a while, I get to stackoverflow to find some "nice to have" feature I would use in vanilla Visual Studio. 90% of the time, the accepted answer is using Resharper. I find this really annoying because Resharper is quite clunky and adds significant overhead on the IDE...

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about previous versions, but in vanilla Visual Studio 2017, you can actually add a constructor parameter

```
public SomeClass(ISomeService service)
{ 
}
```

Then put your cursor on `service` and from "Quick actions" you can chose `Introduce and initialize field _someService` which will do what you want :

```
private readonly ISomeService _someService;

public SomeClass(ISomeService service)
{ 
    _someService = service;
}
```

Comment: I misread your comment but had a happy accident: You  can also put your cursor on the declaration and choose a Quick Action to add the declared property/field to a constructor. This just saved me a lot of time, thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add code snippets as you like, defining it in XAML and adding it the editior, you can use place holders like "class name" to use it as a constructor for example, and then place your variables in it as static text

I don't want to write the code because it's duplicated
you can check out how to do it here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

you can also see this question:
[How can I automatically generate a constructor that receives and stores services for free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154790/how-can-i-automatically-generate-a-constructor-that-receives-and-stores-services)

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do with the ISomeService and IAnotherService is to do dependency inversion.

I would strongly recommend you combine this with a dependency injection framework. There are many available but one i would recommend is MEF. MEF is build into the .net framework. For example your code would look like this with MEF

```
[Export(typeof(ISomeService))]
public class SomeService : ISomeService {
}


public class SomeClass {

   [Import]
   public ISomeService SomeService {get; set;}

   [Import]
   public IAnotherService AnotherService {get; set;}

}
```

Now MEF will actually ensure your SomeService and AnotherService Properties are filled when your class is created. It will construct (if needed) a instance of SomeService, fill all it's dependencies and put it in the right property. You can even control if you want your services instantiated as singletons or as a new service instance each time you need one.

for more details on MEF you can look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee155691(v=vs.110).aspx

This should avoid writing the many constructors that do nothing other than initializing services.

Comment: I'm using simpleinjector. I wasn't asking how to do di. Seems what you do is just property injection, which I want to avoid since it encourages god like classes.

Comment: you were askind how to avoid writing tedious boilerplating. If i have a IGodService property or if i add IGodService as an argument to a constructor. Either one allows a developer to write poor code. This way (propertyInjection) just avoids the boilerplate

Comment: You are right about the tedious boilerplating, thanks for the suggestion. What I meant was the class itself (where one is injecting) is more likely to become a godclass with property injection, because you don't see clear how many dependencies you are actually injecting. Not that it is wrong per se (that's a whole new discussion) and certainly a relevant answer, just not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik's JustCode can do exactly what you need.
if you have an unused argument in the constructor you can create a field and initialise it.
http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode/quick-fixes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for exactly this when I found this [library](https://github.com/gilles-leblanc/Sniptaculous) of snippets. Depending on how many parameters you need, you can use ctor1p, ctor2p.. so on. It creates the constructor with number of params specified and also generates a private field corresponding to each of the injected param.

It works just fine when you're writing the constructor for the first time.

If you have an existing constructor with/without parameters and you'd like to inject a new parameter using these snippets, you will have to rewrite your constructor which will be difficult than just injecting the parameter manually and using ctrl + ..